# Building a Tree from a List<Node>

Tags: java, tree

this is my incoming data

```
id  parent  name
--  ------  ----
B2  A2      XYZ_1
A1  NULL    XYZ_2
B3  A3      XYZ_3
A2  NULL    XYZ_4
B1  A1      XYZ_5
A3  NULL    XYZ_6
C1  B1      XYZ_7
C2  B1      XYZ_8
```

and I'd like to build a tree which would look like this

```
NULL
|-- A1
|   |-- B1
|       |-- C1
|       |-- C2
|
|-- A2
|   |-- B2
|
|-- A3
|   |-- B3
|
```

My code looks like this

```
        Map< Optional< String >, List< Feature > > dividedByParentId = features.stream()
            .collect( groupingBy( feature -> Optional.ofNullable( feature.getParentId() ) ) );
```

```
    static Node< Feature > buildTree( Node< Feature > aCurrent, Object aId )
    {
        if( dividedByParentId.size() == 0 )
        {
            return aCurrent;
        }

        if( !dividedByParentId.containsKey( Optional.ofNullable( aId ) ) )
        {
            return aCurrent;
        }

        if( aCurrent == null )
        {
            Feature root = dividedByParentId.remove( Optional.ofNullable( aId ) )
                .get( 0 );

            Node< Feature > rootNode = new Node<>( root );
            Object rootId = root.getId();

            aCurrent = buildTree( rootNode, rootId );
        }
        else
        {
            List< Feature > features = dividedByParentId.remove( Optional.of( aId ) );

            for( Feature feature : features )
            {
                Node< Feature > node = new Node<>( feature );
                Node< Feature > newFeatureNode = aCurrent.addChild( node );

                buildTree( newFeatureNode, feature.getId() );
            }
        }

        return aCurrent;
    }

    static class Node< T >
    {

        private final T data;
        private final List< Node< T > > children = new ArrayList<>();
        private Node< T > parent = null;

        public Node( T data )
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node< T > addChild( Node< T > child )
        {
            child.setParent( this );
            this.children.add( child );
            return child;
        }

        public void addChildren( List< Node< T > > children )
        {
            children.forEach( each -> each.setParent( this ) );
            this.children.addAll( children );
        }

        public List< Node< T > > getChildren()
        {
            return children;
        }

        public T getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

        private void setParent( Node< T > parent )
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public Node< T > getParent()
        {
            return parent;
        }

    }
```

The incoming data may be unsorted.
How can I do better? My code seems to work if there is only one parent=NULL element.
What should I change if I want to use it for the case if there are more than one null parent?

Comment: Create a root node with a null id.

Comment: But now I have one question more. If my nodes have parent_id == NULL everything works correctly. But it is possible, that there will be some nodes with not null parent_id. How could I create a tree from them?

Comment: Are you asking what to do if `M1` lists `L1` as its parent, but there is no `L1` node in the list? Isn't that for *you* to decide what the result of that should be?